# How to classify video frames to frames containing objects and meaningless frames

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, classification, video-processing

I want to do some detection and classification work on video frames, however, there are too many frames in a video to be processed, so I want to find which frames contain objects and which frames are meaningless(not contain objects or faces) so that I can save some time by detecting on less frames.

I already test Gist and SVM, trying to separate images containing dogs(pascal voc) from forest scene images(15 scene dataset), but the accuracy on test data is very low(less than 50%).

Is there any other feature or algorithm suitable for this task? Also is there any data set suitable for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into visual saliency detection methods. If there are saliency clusters, these frames likely contain objects.